# Webservice returns only System.Xml.XmlDocument string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-services, c#-4.0

When I call my webservice, it only returns the string "System.Xml.XmlDocument" rather than the actual XML. What do I need to change to get it to return an actual XML document?

```
 public XmlDocument GetCommoditiesXmlDocument() {
            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);

            //gets XML as XmlElement

            quotes.WriteTo(xtw);
            xdoc.LoadXml(sw.ToString());
            return xdoc;
        }
```

I'm using .NET 4.0 (and MVC3 if it matters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.Net MVC does not know how to serialize an `XmlDocument` into an HTTP response.

Instead, you should return the XML source directly:

```
return Content(sw.ToString(), "text/xml");
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I actually get the XML passed to my service as an XmlElement. If there a way to serialize that into an HTTP response?

Comment: +1 It looks like the Content class is intended to be used with master pages in Web Forms (though I may be wrong), but you did set me on the right track. I ended up using 'Response.ContentType = "text/xml";' Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: @Llepwryd: Use the `Content()` _method_ in the controller.